# DAX query to filter Invoices where at least one line item contains a particular product

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an invoice table with columns including InvoiceNo and ProductID.  I need to be able to filter so that it returns all Invoices that contain a particular Product.  When this filter is applied, it needs to only display the invoices with that product, but it should show all products on that invoice.

For example, I have the following table:

```
InvoiceNo   ProductID
111         ProdA
111         ProdB
111         ProdC
222         ProdA
222         ProdB
```

I only want to display invoices that have ProdC.  When filtered, it needs to show

```
InvoiceNo   ProductID
111         ProdA
111         ProdB
111         ProdC
```

I have tried the following DAX Measure:

```
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(Invoice),
    SUMMARIZE(
        FILTER(
            SUMMARIZE(
                 Invoice
                ,Invoice[InvoiceNo]
                ,Invoice[ProductID]
            )
            ,Invoice[ProductID] = "ProductC"
        )
    ,Invoice[InvoiceNo]
    )
)
```

But when I apply the filter (where measure > 0), it only returns the following

```
InvoiceNo   ProductID
111         ProdC
```

If I was doing this in SQL, I would use the following query:

```
select 
     [InvoiceNo]
    ,[ProductID]
from
    [Invoice] 
where
    [InvoiceNo] in (SELECT [InvoiceNo] FROM [Invoice] where [ProductID] = 'ProdC')
```

---

### UPDATED: 19th July

A further complication is that we also have a Qty Column, which can contain the value 0.  So an updated table would be

```
InvoiceNo   ProductID   Qty
111         ProdA       1
111         ProdB       2
111         ProdC       1
222         ProdA       1
222         ProdB       3
333         ProdA       1
333         ProdB       2
333         ProdC       0
```

I want to exclude Invoice 333 from my result, because while I am looking for invoices that contain ProdC, I only want them if ProdC qty is > 0.

Comment: Depending on your Invoice table size you could duplicate that table and create a many-to-many relationship between the InvoiceNo columns of both tables. Use one table as ProductID filter and you get the desired rows from the other table.

Comment: Hi @ChristianWelsch  Thanks for the suggestion.  The Invoice table is quite large.  Also, the model is an on prem SSAS tabular model, and I wanted to try and solve this in DAX (using Power BI report measure if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This measure will do the trick

```
Active = 
    SUMX (
        Products ;
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( Products[InvoiceNo] ) ;
            ALL ( Products ) ;
            Products[ProductID] = "ProdC" ;
            Products[Qty] <> 0 ;
            Products[InvoiceNo] = EARLIER ( Products[InvoiceNo] )
        )
    )
```

First you make sure you perform the calculation on a row level with the iterator SUMX. This makes it possible to relate to the invoice number of that particular line and compare it against a filtered version of the product table based on product C and simply count the results.

Comment: Thanks Jelle.  That works well, but I have a complication.  Can you look at my update that I added to the main question?  I need to exclude rows where ProdC Qty is 0.

Comment: I think changing the condition from `Products[ProductID] = "Prod C" ; ` to `AND ( Products[ProductID] = "ProdC" ; Products[Qty] <> 0 ); ` will do the trick

Comment: When I do this, I get an error saying "The expression contains multiple columns, but only a single column can be used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression'

Comment: You are right, stupid mistake, see my update for the working version, that should do the trick.